# Explaining requestAnimationFrame shim layer

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I'm looking at the [following code from Paul Irish on the requestAnimationFrame shim layer](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). I want to generate this js from another language, so I'm trying to wrap my head around exactly what is going on. (You can [see it being used in an animation here](http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/requestanimationframe/)).

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){                //1
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||       //2
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||       //3
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||       //4
          function( callback ){                       //5
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);   //6
          };                                          //7
})();                                                 //8
                                                      //9
(function animloop(){                                 //10
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);                         //11
  render();                                           //12
})();                                                 //13
```

My question is - **What is happening on lines 2-4?** We appear to be getting function handles, joining them togther in an OR operation - and then assigning the result of the `OR` operation to the anonymous function in line 1 - which is then assigned to the var `window.requestAnimFrame`.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the helpful answers - I just want to make sure I have this correct - **is the below an accurate representation of what is going on?** ([Here is the original](http://jsfiddle.net/vDtbw/)) ([Here is the version with the more explicit code](http://jsfiddle.net/e5g2e/).)

```
var myfunc = function() {
    if (typeof(window.requestAnimationFrame) != "undefined") {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame;
    } else if (typeof(window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame) != "undefined") {
        return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
    } else if (typeof(window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) != "undefined") {
        return window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
    } else {
        return function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    }
};
window.requestAnimFrame = myfunc;
```

Comment: yeah, that's a reasonable interpretation. however in javascript you typically use falsyness rather than explicitly checking for undefined or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript LOGICAL OR (these are not binary ORs) will work with "truthy" values - consider e.g.

```
window.foo = window.foo || function() {};
```

In this case because window.foo does not exist, we would return the second opearnd , if it did - then OR expression would evaluate to the first operand.  A null or undefined value is "falsey" - although there are other falsey values - google to find out what they are.

You can read it like this :

Assign the property requestAnimFrame to the output of a function that invokes itself.  This is an odd concept but one that is typically employed because of JavaScript's scoping rules, it prevents any variables inside that function leaking into the global scope.  The important thing to note here is on line 7 the () at the end invokes the function expression started on line 1.

That function returns either window.requestAnimationFrame OR window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame OR window.mozRequestAnimationFrame or lastly if non of those exist (and hence are falsey) return the function which implements request animation frame as a timeout - this being the shim.

In the end you get requestAnimFrame pointing at a function, it is either the already existing built in function with the standard name or the vendor prefixed name or the shim function.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

2nd line is requesting a new frame for general browser.
3rd line is for browser like Chrome , Safari.
4th line is for Mozilla Firefox.
so it is a generalized for every browser.

and else is explained why `requestAnimationFrame()` is better than `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

This code is effectively checking to see if an existing browser implementation of `requestAnimationFrame` exists, if it does not find one by that name it goes on to check various browser specific implementations by checking their respective property names. If all fails, a [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) implementation is ultimately provided.

To see how this works, consider the logic of the OR operator:

- Return the left hand expression if it "truthy", otherwise return the right hand expression.

Therefore we are effectively traversing a chain until we find an expression that is defined (not "falsey"). Note that functions are "truthy".

For example, try this in your browser console:

```
false || 0 || 1 || "Yes"; // returns 1, the first truthy value
true || 1 || false || 0; // returns true, the first truthy value 
false || 0 || "Yes";  // returns "Yes", the first truthy value
false || false || 0; // returns 0, the last value since nothing was truthy
false || 0 || function () {} || false || 1; // returns function () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just returning the first function that isn't null, so basically returning the correct function for the browser the user is using. That isn't a binary OR it is just a conditional OR operator.